# Syntax highlighting not working in Emacs (in Python mode)

Tags: python, themes, syntax-highlighting

When I `Python-mode` I have noticed that occasionally my syntax highlighting is not working.

I have noticed this when using the `Cyberpunk` theme as well as the `Tango-Dark` theme.

Closing and reopening the file corrects the highlighting for any previously written code but it remains broken for any new code.

I do not know how to debug this or what the issue could be so I would be very appreciate of any help.

[image: Example]

Here you can see an example (only `#Plan route`) should be grayed out.

Comment: It will be very useful to add/use other themes, as ```spacemacs-theme``` or ```moe-theme``` and the package ```theme-looper``` to switch between them to see which one "works" and which not, with the same buffer. The ```theme-looper``` can change a theme just with key combination ```C-|```

Comment: @Ian I confirmed it is not the theme and updated the question.  Thanks.

Comment: Then it worths to report it here: https://gitlab.com/python-mode-devs/python-mode/issues. There is one case similar with yours, but in interactive python.

Comment: @Ian it is reported here: https://gitlab.com/python-mode-devs/python-mode/issues/52